# What is a good visa agent for obtaining a Chinese visa from the NY consulate?

Tags: visas, china, recommendations, new-york-city

As a followup to [an earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9589/how-can-i-tell-if-a-visa-agent-is-trustworthy): I'm planning to travel to China shortly, and I'm looking into visa agents - those companies that will accept your passport and application documents by FedEx or UPS (etc.) shipment, submit the application on your behalf, pick up the passport with visa and ship it back to you. I want to be very certain that whatever visa agent I use will keep my passport secure and return it in the time frame that they say they will. Can anyone recommend a good visa agent which operates with the Chinese consulate in New York City? I'm primarily interested in a good record with respect to passport safety and prompt service; cost is a secondary concern.

Comment: Make sure that you have to apply in the NYC office, it is really not that difficult to apply for a visa from the USA to China.   Why are you so worried about sending your passport, if they lose it then get another one, sounds like you should just go yourself.

Comment: @MaoYiyi I have neither the time nor the money to replace a lost passport, and besides, who knows what someone else could do with it? I do know that going there myself is an option, but for purposes of this question let's suppose that is not possible for some reason. (Traveling to New York myself would be considerably more expensive and much more disruptive to my schedule than using an agent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using [China Visa Service Center](http://www.mychinavisa.com/) and had no problems. It took around two weeks from application to the return of my passport with the visa in it.

Comment: (accepting because this is the answer that worked for me, even though I have no problem with the other answers)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have experience specifically with the NY consulate, but I have used [VisaHQ](http://www.visahq.com/) for various visas and they were fast and reliable. I believe they apply for your visas through the consulates located in Washington DC.

Answer (score 4):

I used [CIBT](http://cibtvisas.com) once to get a Chinese business visa. I got my visa in less than a week, and didn't have any issues. Of course, this is just one data point. CIBT fee was around $100 (my employer covered it).

Answer (score 0):

I used China Visa Service Center two or three times. Excellent service.

Comment: Could you please add something more to your answer? Right now it's very low quality without any references.

Comment: I suppose it also doesn't really add anything to my answer, which makes the same recommendation.